# Service Fabric: There was an error during download. Failed to download container image

Tags: docker-compose, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

*edit: I have updated this question with more detail*

I'm trying to deploy an Docker compose to Service Fabric. This cluster is a custom setup using three vm's (Windows Server 2016 Datacenter with Containers) on Azure running the latest version (CodeVersion 6.0.219.9494).

I'm using VSTS with the 'Deploy docker-compose application to a Service Fabric cluster' task to deploy the docker compose file. VSTS uses a custom build server (Server 2016) on which Service Fabric SDK 2.7 is installed. I couldn't install 2.8 because the task in VSTS is not compatible, see https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/5505.

So far, so good. But when Service Fabric deploys the container I receive the following error (In Service Fabric Explorer): There was an error during download. Failed to download container image erwinstaal/dockerdemo. This image has been pushed to a public repo on Docker Hub. However, when I use the Docker images command on one of the nodes the image has been downloaded. Does anyone have a clue on what could be going on?

Comment: When do you get the error? During VSTS build/release or in azure Service Fabric? Where is erwinstaal/dockerdemo image pushed to? Can you share the detail build/release log on the OneDrive?

Comment: I get the error in Service Fabric. The release in VSTS runs succesfully. The image is pushes to a public repo on docker hub. Is there any log in Service Fabric I could share? The container is a Windows IIS container running a ASP.net 4.5 mvc app.

Comment: can you rdp into one of the nodes and pull the image & run the container manually?

Comment: I didn't need to pull the image as Service Fabric had already done so. Using docker run I can run the container. When I browse to it's ip I do receive a 500 error from IIS but I don't think that's the problem here.

Comment: I figured it out. During the build and push of the image there's a checkbox 'Include Latest Tag' which I hadn't checked. So I didn't have an image on Docker Hub with tag Latest. Now that the box is checked the deployment succeeds!